# RxJS: Get throttled items

Tags: rxjs

Would you please let me know how to get throttled items with RxJS? Specifically let's have a look at the code below:

```
// test.js
var Rx = require('rx'),
    Subject = Rx.Subject,
    source = new Subject(),
    count = 0;

// generate items
setInterval(
    () => {
        source.onNext(count++)
    }, 100
)

var windowDuration = 200;
source.throttle(windowDuration).subscribe(console.log);
```

The code above will print out:

```
λ bigsonata test → node test.js
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
23
```

The throttled items in this case is odd numbers.

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).filter(i => i % 2 === 0).subscribe((x) => {
    console.log(x);
});
```

output:

> 2
>
> 4
>
> 6
>
> 8
>
> 10

see this JSBin

https://jsbin.com/xakato/3/edit?js,console,output

Comment: I think OP wants to get events that were filtered out by `throttle` operator.